# How to find location of a stand alone app on windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, azure

On `Windows 10`, I installed `Storage Explorer` from MS official site [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/). It's a `stand alone app`. But I don't know how to launch (get to) it.

At the end of installation it launched successfully and I used it as well. So I know it is somewhere on the machine. But after closing it I don't know how to open/launch it again. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default installation path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer`

You also could find it on Start Menu.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The .exe file is named StorageExplorer.exe. You should be able to type that string into File Explorer (focus on your C: drive) and it should come right up. I use Voidtools Everything, which is an even faster search tool:

[image]